# filter dataframe columns as you iterate through rows and create dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following table of data in a spreadsheet:

```
Name    Description Value
foo     foobar      5
baz     foobaz      4
bar     foofoo      8
```

I'm reading the spreadsheet and passing the data as a dataframe.

I need to transform this table of data to json following a specific schema.

I have the following script:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Description'] == 'foofoo':
            print(row.to_dict())
```

which return:

```
{'Name': 'bar', 'Description': 'foofoo', 'Value': '8'}
```

I want to be able to filter out a specific column. For example, to return this:

```
{'Name': 'bar', 'Description': 'foofoo'}
```

I know that I can print only the columns I want with this `print(row['Name'],row['Description'])` however this is only returning me values when I also want to return the key.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do the filtering before you convert to a dictionary.

Comment: @anky_91 Easily the most sensible answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this entire thing only to realize that [@anky_91 had already suggested it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286849/filter-dataframe-columns-as-you-iterate-through-rows-and-create-dictionary#comment106639767_60286849). Oh well...

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "name": ["foo", "abc", "baz", "bar"],
    "description": ["foobar", "foofoo", "foobaz", "foofoo"],
    "value": [5, 3, 4, 8],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

print(df, end='\n\n')

rec_dicts = df.loc[df["description"] == "foofoo", ["name", "description"]].to_dict(
    "records"
)

print(rec_dicts)
```

Output:

```
  name description  value
0  foo      foobar      5
1  abc      foofoo      3
2  baz      foobaz      4
3  bar      foofoo      8

[{'name': 'abc', 'description': 'foofoo'}, {'name': 'bar', 'description': 'foofoo'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

After converting to dictionary you can delete the key which you don't need with:

```
del(row[value])
```

Now the dictionary will have only name and description.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the opposite of this? If I want to select only specific columns from my dictionary?

Comment: To select a specific column from a dict your could .get(). row.get('value').

Comment: @SimonBreton Same as using any plain old dictionary!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

s="""Name,Description,Value
foo,foobar,5
baz,foobaz,4
bar,foofoo,8
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Description'] == 'foofoo':
        print(row[['Name', 'Description']].to_dict())
```

Result:

```
{'Name': 'bar', 'Description': 'foofoo'}
```